# RatingBar is cut off horizontally when displayed inside a weighted LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, ratingbar, android-layout-weight

I'm currently trying to use weighted `LinearLayout`s in order to split the width of the screen equally. In one of those halves, I wanted to position a `RatingBar` directly in the centre. The layout I have currently is as below:

```
<LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:baselineAligned="false"
   android:orientation="horizontal">

   <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:orientation="horizontal">

      <RatingBar
         android:id="@+id/rating_bar"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:isIndicator="true"
         android:max="5"
         android:numStars="5"
         android:scaleX="0.5"
         android:scaleY="0.5"
         tools:rating="3" />

   </LinearLayout>

   <View
      android:layout_width="1dp"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
      android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
      android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

   <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:orientation="horizontal">

      <TextView
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="@string/test" />

   </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The issue I am finding is that the `RatingBar` is being cut off horizontally and only showing 3.5 stars. If I move the `RatingBar` out of a weighted `LinearLayout` then it displays as I would expect. I do not know of another way to equally split the screen other than using weighting. A solution for either splitting the screen equally without weighting or a way to display the `RatingBar` correctly inside would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

use this ..

```
<RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/rating_bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:isIndicator="true"
        android:max="5"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.RatingBar.Indicator"
        android:numStars="5"
        android:scaleX="0.5"
        android:scaleY="0.5"
        tools:rating="3" />
```